# I can't install my developed iOS application in iOS version 7.0.4 and version 8.0.2

Tags: ios, ios7

I am developing an iOS application. When I downloaded my completed iOS application, it is ok in most of  iOS version. But it don't work in iOS version 7.0.4 and version 8.0.2. When I do downloading my application, It don't happen nothing. It don't show any error messages. Nothing Happening , No Install. So, Would you give me any idea what I should solve this problem?
Thank in advance.